# TOC longer than 1 page messes with Tikz absolute positioning on following pages

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, positioning

I have an issue where a TOC on more than one page, ruins the tikz-positioning for the rest of the pdf.
Example:

[image]

The header  has been moved to the bottom of the page where it usually stays on the top of the page.

Now to the code:
Load the header into the page like this:

```
\begin{document}

    \input{graphics/pagestyle/titlepage.tex}
    \pagecolor{none}
    \newpage

    \AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPic}

    \tableofcontents
```

\BackgroundPic is defined like this:

```
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\headerbg{
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=WLEBlue1] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
          \node (label) at (10,1.5){
            \includegraphics[width=660pt]{graphics/pagestyle/header_bg.png}
          };
          \node (label) at (1.4,1.5){
            \includegraphics[width=60pt]{graphics/pagestyle/WLE_Logo.png}
          };
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  }

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{
\headerbg
\put(0,0){
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (-10,12.5)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \draw [WLEBlue1, fill=WLEBlue1] (0,0) -- (0.05,0) -- (0.05,-22.2) -- (0.25,-22.2) -- (0.25, -23) -- (0, -23);
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (8.5,12.5)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \draw [WLEBlue1, fill=WLEBlue1] (-1, -23) -- (0, -23) -- (0, -22) -- (-0.08, -22) -- (-0.08, -22.92) -- (-1, -22.92);
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
}}}
        \newpage
```

It works totally fine when the TOC is only 1 page long, with 2 pages it bugs up.
Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

*Update:* Posted this as a comment a while ago, but decided to move it up here for more visiblity: [Here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5166b069dac9aae1446c09f1#) is an online version at ShareLatex showing the issue. You can see, and edit some example code there and compile it for yourself.

*Update:* Tried removing the nesting of the TikzPictures but it didn't help. Code without nested pictures:

```
\newcommand*\headerbg{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \node(base) at (current page.north west) {};
        \node at ($(base)+(9.1,0.7)$){
            \includegraphics[width=660pt]{header_bg.png}
        };
        \node at ($(base)+(0.5,0.7)$){
            \includegraphics[width=60pt]{WLE_Logo.png}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

*Update:* It's the Chapter Style that is causing the issue, removing the chapter style removes the issue aswell.

```
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (0,0)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[WLEBlue2, fill=WLEBlue2] (0,0) rectangle
          (\textwidth,1cm);
        \node[
            inner xsep=1ex,
            text width=\linewidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
            align=left] at (9,0.5)
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
```

Comment: Can you complete your example into a compilable one ? It's quite long anyway so why not adding a few more lines and make it start from `\documentclass{...}` to `\end{document}`. Without reading thoroughly I am pretty sure it's due to the nesting of TikZ pictures.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: [Here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5166b069dac9aae1446c09f1#) is an online version at ShareLatex showing the issue.
Can't get more compilable than that ;)

Comment: @percusse I removed the nesting of the TikZ pictures but with no luck

Comment: @LukasPJ Well, I did a test with the snippets you provided; since I didn't have your images I had to use the demo option for graphicx, and I couldn't detect any problems. Please see the code that I used here: http://pastebin.com/7k8qTP4h . Processing that simpledocument produces no undesired behaviour. If you want us to detect the problem, you will have to provide a sample document like mine (*complete* and simple) but allowing us to really reproduce the problem.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Isn't this complete enough?
[https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5166b069dac9aae1446c09f1#](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5166b069dac9aae1446c09f1#)
Anyways I found the cause.. It's actually the chapters, I wanted to remove them to clean the sample up a bit and then it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, the issue was in the chapter style.
I removed the *remember picture* options on the tikzpictures which seems to have resolved the issue. I'm not entirely sure why the *remember picture* option would cause this issue.

```
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \node at (0,0)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \draw[WLEBlue2, fill=WLEBlue2] (0,0) rectangle
          (\textwidth,1cm);
        \node[
            inner xsep=1ex,
            text width=\linewidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
            align=left] at (9,0.5)
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
```